# Is it possible to run marklogic7 appbuilder generated application from the file system, not the module database?

Tags: marklogic

In the past I used to be able to generate the search applications using Marklogic's app builder,  copy the contents of the created modules database to the file system,  change the configuration of HTTP server and start customizing away.

However, this doesn't work with the new Marklogic7 applications.  When I move the application modules to the file system and run the app I get the generic REST API page.  Apparently the REST API rewriter script doesn't pick up configuration if the app modules are not stored in the database.   Is there any way around this?

The reason I'd like to use above workflow is that I can use version control, and automated deployers.  Having the app in the modules database severely limits choice of dev tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't think there's a direct way to do what you're looking for, using the workflow I [laid out in this blog post](http://blog.davidcassel.net/2013/08/capturing-an-app-building-application-with-roxy/) lets you use version control and makes it easy to script automated deployers. It makes use of the Roxy Deployer ([intro](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/wiki/Tutorials)).

Comment: +1.  Using the modules database in no way limits your ability to manage your application with vesrsion control and automated deploymnet. In fact it makes it easier because as you move to clusters of MarkLogic servers deploying directly to the Modules Database will automatically deploy your app to all machines in the clusters.   You just need a tool that can copy files into and out of MarkLogic via the command line, then you can script to your hearts content.   Another tool is xmlsh using the marklogic extension http://www.xmlsh.org/ModuleMarkLogic this adds simple CLI commands to work with ML.